In Bokeh, how can I update the color of lines when updating a multiline data source?
I want to update a multi_line in a bokeh figure. As part of the updates, I need to adjust colors.
First, I make a simple figure:
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure()
# create a dummy multiline so that we can update it later with new data
p.multi_line(xs=[[0,1]], ys=[[0,1]], name='my_lines')

show(p)

This gives fine results:

Then I try to update the lines:
lines_ds = p.document.get_model_by_name('my_lines').data_source

lines_ds.data = dict(
    xs=[[1,2,3],[0,0]],
    ys=[[0,1,0],[0,1]],
    color=['black','red']
)
show(p)

This updates my x and y data, but not the colors:

How can I update the colors of the lines? I already tried colors instead of color.
I'm not entirely opposed to simply creating an entirely new figure each time I need to update (multiple times per second), but I've been told that the right way to use bokeh is to update your objects rather than deleting and recreating things.

I found my own solution. I needed to change 2 things. First, line_color needed to be part of the original creation of the multi_line (alternatively, you could use color instead of line_color here):
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure()
# create a dummy multiline so that we can update it later with new data
p.multi_line(xs=[[0,1]], ys=[[0,1]], name='my_lines', line_color=['red'])

show(p)

Second, I needed to change color to line_color when making the update:
lines_ds = p.document.get_model_by_name('my_lines').data_source

lines_ds.data = dict(
    xs=[[1,2,3],[0,0]],
    ys=[[0,1,0],[0,1]],
    line_color=['black','red']
)
show(p)


There is no need to set the color parameter in the initial figure. The color is made to apply the same color to all lines and is always overwritten by line_color, if existing. This means you could also start with line_color=['red'].

If I have neither color nor line_color in the initial figure, I cannot update line_color in the future. So, you're right that I don't need color if I have line_color instead. And I like that as a suggestion, that way I'm using the same specific color variable in both places. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.
